# Seaborn, only plot 3 ticks on the y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have been trying to get 3 ticks on my y axis in a seaborn plot using `plt.MaxNLocator(3)`, but for some reason it occasionally gives me 2 ticks.

Please let me know if anyone can recreate the issue from the code below, or suggest any workaround -

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
g.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

I believe that there should be 3 ticks on the y axis.
I would just increase the number to 4 - but this only happens occasionally depending on the axis scale so it is not ideal to tweak it for every figure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: MaxN means maximal 3 in your case. Look [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) to see the different locators. Maybe the `Index Locator` would be something for you

Comment: Try `plt.MaxNLocator(3, min_n_ticks=3)`.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for the link. So I suppose the question is "what is the easiest way to get three ticks on the y axis with Seaborn?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to specify the minimum number of ticks to be 3. From the [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) docs:

> **min_n_ticks** int, default: 2

```
g.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3, min_n_ticks=3))
```